# Android Случайная ImageView при клике по ImageButton

Tags: android, button, случайные-числа, imageview

Подскажите, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку (ImageButton) происходила смена картинки на случайную, все они названы tile1, tile2... и т.д.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton buttonRandom;
    ImageView tileImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tileImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tile);
        buttonRandom = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonRandom);
        View.OnClickListener butRnd = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile2);
            }
        };
        buttonRandom.setOnClickListener(butRnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее))) Все работает прекрасно

Comment: [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] imageRes = new int[]{R.drawable.tile1, R.drawable.tile2, R.drawable.tile3};
Random r = new Random();
tileImage.setImageResource(imageRes[r.nextInt(imageRes.length)]);
```